# Using API in Sandbox Mode on Commercial Website

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I would like to display our photos posted on Instagram on our commercial web site using Instagram API.

1. I think that Sandbox Mode is sufficient because the number of pictures we want to display is 20 or less, but is there a regulations problem in using Sandbox for use on a commercial websites?
2. Also, is it necessary to switch to Live Mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially Instagram says

> You do not need to submit for review for this use case. If you are a developer and you want to display Instagram content on your website, then you do not need to submit your app for review. By using a client in sandbox mode, you can still access the last 20 media of any sandbox user that grants you permission.

So actually no need to go **Live** mode.

P.S.
[Here](http://prntscr.com/e6gaxl) is the link to all cases.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. We will use Sandbox mode.